# Graphic proof of an inequality between sequence ratios

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I would like to verify my proof for the following claim.

> Let $b_i$ be a positive decreasing sequence, $j<k$ two integers and $d$ a positive number. Prove that:
>   $$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^j{b_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^k{b_i}} > \frac{\sum_{i=1}^j{(b_i+d)}}{\sum_{i=1}^k{(b_i+d)}} $$

My proof goes backwards from the claim. Multiplying by the denominators gives:
$$ (\sum_{i=1}^j{b_i})(kd+\sum_{i=1}^k{b_i}) > (\sum_{i=1}^k{b_i})(jd+\sum_{i=1}^j{b_i}) $$

Subtracting common terms and dividing by $d$:

$$ k(\sum_{i=1}^j{b_i}) > j(\sum_{i=1}^k{b_i}) $$

This inequality is proved by the following picture, in which $k=6$ and $j=4$:

[image]

The left-hand side is the $k\times j$ rectangle at the left (colored  cyan&green). The right-hand side is the $j\times  k$ rectangle at the top (colored yellow&green).

The green region is common to both sides; the difference is the cyan vs. yellow regions.

Both these areas have exactly the same number of elements: $j(k-j)$.

Because the sequence is decreasing, each element in the cyan region is larger than an element in the yellow region. Hence, the sum of the cyan region is larger than the sum of the yellow region. Hence, the LHS is larger than the RHS.

---

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is correct. By the way, we can prove it directly as the following :   $$\begin{align}k\sum_{i=1}^{j}b_i-j\sum_{i=1}^{k}b_i&=(j+k-j)\sum_{i=1}^{j}b_i-j\left(\sum_{i=1}^{j}b_i+\sum_{i=j+1}^{k}b_i\right)\\&=(k-j)\sum_{i=1}^{j}b_i-j\sum_{i=j+1}^{k}b_i\\&\gt (k-j)jb_j-j(k-(j+1)+1)b_{j+1}\\&=(k-j)j(b_j-b_{j+1})\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$